# My own modules can't be found -> Unresolved Reference

Tags: python, import, module, python-import, importerror

I have a Python project called `restapi`. The folder structure is the following:

```
restapi
|-data
|  |-[...]
|-docs
|  |-[...]
|-src
|  |-app.py
|  |-flaskWrapper.py
|  |-imageLoader.py
|  |-modelLoader.py
|  |-ocr.py
|-test
|  |-[...]
```

In `app.py` I `import` some stuff:

```
from imageLoader import Img
from modelLoader import Model
from PIL import Image
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
```

But it doesn't work and the error message is `Unresolved reference 'imageLoader'` and the same with `modelLoader`. Does anyone have an idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Is it an error message or a PyCharm warning message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That warning seems to be on PyCharm. You have to tell the base/root of your imports, which here is `restapi/src/` so that PyCharm knows that your imports such as `from imageLoader import Img` are relative to the root path `restapi/src/`

[image]

On top of that, make sure that [Python can find those imports](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) when executed by setting the `PYTHONPATH` from the root `restapi/src/`

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/restapi/src
```